# Is there a way to show "File not found" or a message alike when using the `find` command?

Tags: shell, find, aix, ksh

I'm trying to check the existence of several files, without knowing in advance where the files are located.  So, I thought of `find` as the *de facto* utility to do this...  It works as expected, but the problem is that it does not acknowledge the non-existence of files, that is, if a file does not exists under the searched directory then, as you will expect, it's not showed in the results.

I guess this is fine, as the `find` command is meant to find files, which actually exists in the first place (d'oh).  But I wonder if there's a way for the `find` command to return a message like "File not found" or alike, to inform that the file is not there, instead of failing (or succeeding) silently.

I thought that maybe I could workaround the problem by using `find`'s return code by querying `$?`, but even when the file is not found the return code is `0`.

Just an example of what I have...

```
find . -name foo.sh 
find . -name bar.sh
```

and what it returns in case the only file in there is `foo.sh`:

```
./directory/foo.sh
```

What I would like to receive is:

```
./directory/foo.sh
bar.sh not found
```

Does anyone knows of a `find` flag or any other workaround I can use?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try `find . -name foo | grep \/` to set the exit code.

grep looks for any / in the output and returns exit code 1 if none is found

Comment: Genius!  I can use:  `find . -name foo | grep \/ || echo "File not found"`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think *find* has an option to say '*what you looked for was not found*'.

You can count the number of lines returned by *find* and if it's 0 print the 'not found' message. Something like:

```
#/bin/bash

# put find output to a temp file
find . -name 'foo.sh' > /var/tmp/find.tmp.$$

# count the number of lines
COUNT=`wc -l /var/tmp/find.tmp.$$ | awk '{ print $1 }'`


if [ $COUNT -eq 0 ]
then
   # find didn't return any results, so print message
   echo "foo.sh not found"
else
   # find returned results, print them
   cat /var/tmp/find.tmp.$$
fi
# remove temp file
rm /var/tmp/find.tmp.$$
```

That will print the output of the *find* command if there were any results or '*foo.sh not found*' when no results found.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea in case you want to create a wrapper for `find`, but in this case I just wanted a simple one-liner just to be aware that the file is not there.  +1 anyway, cause as I said, it's a good idea.  Thanks!